# ¿cómo mantengo visualizadas las etiquetas al final de la animación?

Tags: ggplot

el problema en este código es que como verán la animación no conserva las etiquetas de las series hasta el final. Solo permanece el de "Zinc":

```
dt$Fecha2 <- as.Date(dt$Fecha, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

s <- ggplot(data=dt,aes(x=Fecha2,y=Indice,color=Metal,label=Metal))+
  geom_line()+
   geom_text(hjust=1) +
   geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(as.Date("2020-03-16")), linetype = "dashed", colour="red", size = 1)+
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  scale_y_log10(breaks=c(75,100,125,150,175,200))+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="2 months", date_labels="%d-%b-%y")+
  
  transition_reveal(Fecha2)

animate(s, fps = 5, end_pause = 10)
```

[image: Imagen del código anterior]

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda. Dejo la base para descargar de google drive:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eQJRdA3njoX_VHOqOjpNlIpwJFnqZyEL?usp=sharing

Comment: Tal vez a quienes tienen más experiencia en ggplot les interese ver los datos que usaste para esto.